# Body Background Image

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning HTML5 and CSS3. I am trying to use an image as "background image" in the body. I want to know if it is possible that the image does not take the entire webpage. I mean can I restrict it to use half of the page and the remaining half should be without the image?

Comment: You'll find lots of information on MDN - [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
background:url(image.png) no-repeat right; or left
```

See this Pages...
[background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

 [@media screen](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Maybe Help you...